# Converting a heavily nested Clojure function to the threaded form

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, ide, expression

I am trying to convert heavily nested expressions in Clojure.
One example is the following:

```
(distinct (flatten (map keys (flatten (filter vector? (vals data))))))
```

The threaded form would be:

```
(->> data vals (filter vector?) flatten (map keys) flatten distinct)
```

Is it possible in Clojure to create a function or macro that help me automate getting the threaded form with the nested form as input? Or are there any third-party tools that I can use?

Comment: I can't think of any use case for such a macro; could you give an example? Or are you asking for a way to do this in your source code with an editor?

Comment: @Elogent Yes. I guess it's use case is the developer's own convenience in refactoring heavily nested code.

Comment: The only reason one would write a macro that converts *from* a nested form *to* a threaded form would be so that they could write the nested form in their source code and have Clojure convert it to the threaded form in the macroexpansion phase. Such a macro would be completely useless, because the threading macros just convert right back to the nested form.

Comment: True, since they are the same in terms of execution. However, it would be useful to know how to do it in terms of string manipulation.

Comment: Note that I am also asking for third-party tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using CIDER, I would recommend [`clj-refactor`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el). It has refactoring capability for both [`->`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el/wiki/cljr-thread-first-all) and [`->>`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el/wiki/cljr-thread-last-all), as well as [a whole bunch of other stuff](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el/wiki).

Comment: Lighttable also has a plugin which will do this: https://github.com/rundis/clj-light-refactor#threading

Answer (score 0):

*Further tooling support:*

**IntelliJ** - Cursive plugin:
Since [version 0.1.29](https://cursive-ide.com/eap.html) provides:

> New Structural Editing commands: Kill Sexp, **Thread/Unthread Form**, Move Form Up/Down.

---

**VS Code** - Calva plugin:
You would use the `Thread Last All` command to get the desired result. Full list of [threading options](https://calva.io/refactoring/) are:

> | Command Title | Command Key |
> | --- | --- |
> | Thread First | clojureLsp.refactor.threadFirst |
> | Thread First All | clojureLsp.refactor.threadFirstAll |
> | Thread Last | clojureLsp.refactor.threadLast |
> | Thread Last All | clojureLsp.refactor.threadLastAll |